# Ubuntu for windows 8

Tags: software-recommendation

To whom it may concern,

I want to purchase ubuntu cd, however I have some doubts as to whether the service will be good. My questions are:

1) If I purchase it for windows 8 - which one will I need ?

2) What happens if I doesn't work / customer satisfaction ?

3) Is this the same a Linux ?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't buy the cd lol. Just get af lashdrive and put the installation no there from the ubuntu site.

Comment: I'm not understanding question 1. Can you be more clear

Comment: Ubuntu is based on Linux. If you don't like ubuntu then install windows 7/8 or whatever os you want

Answer (score 3):

#### What version do i need for Windows 8?

If you have Windows 8, you can either install it alongside in a separate partition by [downloading the desktop version](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), or use the [Windows Installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer). Either way, if your computer came with Windows 8 (rather than you installing it yourself) you should go for Ubuntu 12.10 or 12.04, nothing earlier.

#### What happens if it doesn't work?

You can ask questions here, or take to the [forums](http://ubuntuforums.org) to find solutions to your problem. If you're not satisfied with something, do the same thing. Chances are, someone's of the same opinion, and has made an alternative!

Unless you buy [Ubuntu Advantage](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=667) or [Ubuntu Advantage Advanced](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=668), Canonical (the creators of Ubuntu) won't be providing you with any direct support, although some of their developers do volunteer on here as well.

#### What about Customer Satisfaction?

Remember that this isn't a paid product, it is something you get for free. It doesn't come with a warranty or guarantee in the traditional sense, and you can get rid of it whenever you want.

#### Is this Linux?

Linux is a free, open-source kernel, the very base of your operating system, and is what Ubuntu uses. More commonly, Linux is used to describe (sometimes incorrectly) any open-source operating system. Either way, yes, Ubuntu does boot from a Linux kernel, and is an open-source operating system.

#### So i don't need to purchase anything?

No, you can download, modify and share Ubuntu as you please. The DVDs are there mainly for people that either want a more professional touch, or perhaps have severe bandwidth limitations.

Answer (score 1):

1. The 12.10 release DVD, since it has the  GRUB2 bootloader and kernel support with UEFI. Or wait till 12.04.2 is released to get a more stable version.
2. Can't understand the question. If the purchased DVD doesn't work, contact Canonical. If you don't laike Ubuntu, install another OS.
3. Yes, it is based on the Linux Kernel.